# Imageclick onclicklistener not working with implementation of LayoutInflater

Tags: android

I need to navigate to next page on a image click. Using inflator a getting a view and assigning it to row.By using row I am accessing  the element "learn" which is a ImageView in the  "dialog_layout" view. Now I need to set onclicklister for that "Imgview". I have wrote the code but when I click the imageview it is not navigating. Have I made any error in the code..

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ListViewGallery.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(Parent.getHeight()/2, Parent.getHeight()/2);
            dialog.show();
            ImageView ImgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.learn);
            ImgView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {       
                    Intent intent=new Intent(ListViewGallery.this,LearnLayoutAnimals.class);
                    startActivity(intent);          
                }
            });

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v("dd",e.toString());
        }


    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWXH7.png

Comment: What are you doing with `row` afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inflating the view after you have shown the Dialog, the ImageView you are seeing and the one you have inflated are different objects. Change it like

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ListViewGallery.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

View row=LayoutInflater.from(ListViewGallery.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, parent,false);
ImageView ImgView=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.learn);
ImgView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent=new Intent(ListViewGallery.this,LearnLayoutAnimals.class);
      startActivity(intent);
}
});
dialog.setContentView(row);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: I did like ur code but shows me error I have posted my logcat error above plz see to it. In layout inflator it throws exception

Comment: At LayoutInflater inflater

Comment: One more problem this dialog box is called at the time of a list item select at that point this code fails because it has to show the layout "dialog_layout" and then if i click the image in that it has to navigate. If I change like above code when list item is clicked it opens dialog and throws nullpoint exce.

Comment: I have updated the code with two two new lines. If that is the condition how I can code plz help..

Comment: Add more over from is not applicable for itemclicklistner it shows.

Comment: I don't get what is the issue

Comment: Use `ListViewGallery.this` instead of `this`

Comment: Sorry for asking u again I have updated the code, now without inflating Will I be able to access the elements in the dialog box with the dialog box object of the other layout element.